# USB host-to-host cable driver for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, usb, drivers

I have recently acquired a USB host-to-host cable in order to share my internet connection via USB with my Linux computer (a Raspberry Pi). I am having trouble, however, finding a Windows 7 64-bit driver for the device. The cable seems to be quite old as it came with a Windows XP driver. I have searched the manufacturer's website for a newer driver version to no avail. Is it possible to work around this situation (with a generic driver for instance) or is my case truly hopeless?

Here is the hardware info I found:

Hardware IDS:

```
USB\VID_05E3&PID_0502&REV_0180

USB\VID_05E3&PID_0502
```

Windows device manager recognizes the device as *USB host to host Bridge*

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I only found drives for XP  from 2001 fro the Hardware Ids on some strange websites, so I haven't downloaded the drivers.

If you have the Pro or Ultimate Edition of Windows 7, you can [install and use the XP mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7), which is a VirtualPC Virtual Machine and run this VM to access the Raspberry Pi over the cable.